# How to change State from inside .Map function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, this

I have this function

```
renderCompanies() {
    if (this.props.companies)
      return [
        <div>
          Dashboard hello <div>{this.renderProfile()}</div>
          <div>
            {this.props.companies.map(function(item, i) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div
                    key={i}
                    onClick={item => {
                      this.setState({ currentCompany: item });
                    }}
                  >
                    {i}: {item.name}
                  </div>

                  <button>Delete Company</button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <AddCompanyPopUp />
        </div>
      ];
  }
```

I want to loop though this.props.companies and render a list of items. I want a user to be able to click on a specific item and have the item be saved to state.

This function runs inside another funtion

```
renderEitherMenuOrCompanyList() {
    if (this.state.currentCompany) {
      return <Menu companies={this.state.currentCompany} />;
    } else {
      return <div>{this.renderCompanies()}</div>;
    }
  }
```

Both are already bound to this

```
this.renderCompanies = this.renderCompanies.bind(this);
this.renderProfile = this.renderProfile.bind(this);
this.renderEitherMenuOrCompanyList = this.renderEitherMenuOrCompanyList.bind(this)
```

The renderEitherMenuOrCompanyList function is being called inside the render react function/method.

My problem is that I cannot set the state from the renderCompanies .map function. I keep getting "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" . This should be simple but I have not been able to do it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the function given to `map` is bound as well, or an arrow function:

```
{this.props.companies.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        key={i}
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ currentCompany: item });
        }}
      >
        {i}: {item.name}
      </div>

      <button>Delete Company</button>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: but its already an arrow function?                                                                  
         onClick={item => {
          this.setState({ currentCompany: item });
        }}

Comment: @DavidMbwana Not the actual function given to `map`. Compare your code `this.props.companies.map(function(item, i) { ... }` to my answer.

Comment: Works. great !!

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `this.props.companies.map` isn’t an arrow function, so it creates a new `this`. Change it to an arrow function to preserve the `this` from outside of it.

```
this.props.companies.map( ( item, i ) => { ... } )
```

You’ve also named the argument to `onClick` `item`, but it’s actually the click event. You want the `item` already defined by the `map` function. Name the argument to `onClick` something else, or nothing, to avoid overwriting the `item` variable you actually want.

```
onClick={ () => { ... } }
```